# Is it OK calculating and compare the differences between standardized (z-log) means of different subsets of a dataset?

Tags: standardization, z-score, cohens-d

I have a large dataset of different species-level traits like leaf length, lifespan, height, etc that I am combining with a time-series occurrence dataset to see changes in mean trait values over time. Some basic example of the dataset structure:

Traits

| Species | Leaf length | Height |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10 |
| B | 5 | 15 |
| C | 3 | 35 |
| D | 2 | 50 |
| E | 6 | 60 |
| F | 8 | 90 |

Time series

| Period 1 | Period 2 | Period 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | NA | A |
| B | B | B |
| C | C | NA |
| D | D | D |
| NA | NA | NA |
| F | NA | F |

I would like to be able to compare the relative size of changes between different traits over time to see which traits were emphasized most during different periods.

For this purpose I log- and z-transformed my dataset to standardize it and then calculated the difference in standardized means between two different time periods.This produced sensible results, until I noticed that sometimes the mean z-log score will slightly decrease even though in reality, the untransformed value slightly increased over the same period. Overall, though, I'm fairly happy with the results though I'm not sure if this is meaningful or not.

1. Is comparing differences in standardized means a valid strategy?

But it seems like calculating Cohen's d to estimate the effect size between different periods would also be an option.

2. Would Cohen's d or another method be more appropriate? Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Standardizing a log transformed variate seems an unnecessary first step. What is your motivation for this as opposed to standardizing without the log transformation?

Comment: Some traits are highly skewed, such as lifespan which ranges anywhere from 5000 to 50 years, but with most values falling into the 50-500 year range.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the z-transforms without a prior log transform? Are results consistent? Also, given the skewness, you may want to explore how much outliers are influencing the results. If it's severe, then normal assumption metrics could be supplanted with more robust nonparametric estimators https://www.jstor.org/stable/4616328  Not being an exponent of outlier deletion -- there's information in extreme values -- other options are approaches like bootstrap resampling for a better understanding of the variability.

Comment: The results are consistent, yes, and I'm quite satisfied with them. But I'm not 100% sure if it is mathematically valid to compare differences between means of subsets of standardized data to see how much a mean changes between two periods.

Comment: There are plenty of examples wrt *two period statistical tests*, revert to google for confirmation of this. Why would you be leery of employing them?